# Why does yesod require authorisation here?

Tags: haskell, authorization, yesod

I have a problem with yesod and authorization.

I get to the login page when trying to view blog posts when not logged in.

That is not what I want.

I want to be able to view blog posts even when not logged in.

I have tried to fix it but nothing has worked.

Here is the relevant sections of the code:

```
mkMessage "Blog" "messages" "en"

mkYesod "Blog" [parseRoutes|
/ RootR GET
/blog BlogR GET POST
/blog/#EntryId EntryR GET POST
/auth AuthR Auth getAuth
|]

instance Yesod Blog where
    approot = ApprootStatic "http://localhost:3000"
    defaultLayout = defLayout
    authRoute _ = Just $ AuthR LoginR

    isAuthorized BlogR True = do
      mauth <- maybeAuth
      case mauth of
        Nothing -> return AuthenticationRequired
        Just (Entity _ user)
             | isAdmin user -> return Authorized
             | otherwise    -> unauthorizedI MsgNotAnAdmin

    isAuthorized (EntryR _) True = do
      mauth <- maybeAuth
      case mauth of 
         Nothing -> return AuthenticationRequired
         Just _  -> return Authorized

    isAuthorized _ _ = return Authorized

isAdmin :: User -> Bool
isAdmin user = userEmail user == "email@something.com"

instance YesodPersist Blog where
    type YesodPersistBackend Blog = SqlPersist
    runDB f = do
      master <- getYesod
      let pool = connPool master
      runSqlPool f pool

type Form x = Html -> MForm Blog Blog (FormResult x, Widget)

instance RenderMessage Blog FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage

instance YesodNic Blog

instance YesodAuth Blog where
    type AuthId Blog = UserId
    loginDest _ = RootR
    logoutDest _ = RootR
    authHttpManager = httpManager
    authPlugins _ = [authBrowserId]
    getAuthId creds = do
      let email = credsIdent creds
          user = User email
      res <- runDB $ insertBy user
      return $ Just $ either entityKey id res

getRootR :: Handler RepHtml
getRootR = defaultLayout $ do
             setTitleI MsgHomepageTitle
             [whamlet|
<p>_{MsgWelcomeHomepage}
<p>
    <a href=@{BlogR}>_{MsgSeeArchive}
|]

entryForm :: Form Entry
entryForm = renderDivs $ Entry
            <$> areq textField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgNewEntryTitle) Nothing
            <*> aformM (liftIO getCurrentTime)
            <*> areq nicHtmlField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgNewEntryContent)
            Nothing

getBlogR :: Handler RepHtml
getBlogR = do
  muser <- maybeAuth
  entries <- runDB $ selectList [] [Desc EntryPosted]
  (entryWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost entryForm
  defaultLayout $ do
             setTitleI MsgBlogArchiveTitle
             [whamlet|
$if null entries
    <p>_{MsgNoEntries}
$else
    <ul>
        $forall Entity entryId entry <- entries
            <li>
                <a href=@{EntryR entryId}>#{entryTitle entry}
$maybe Entity _ user <- muser
    $if isAdmin user
        <form method=post enctype=#{enctype}>
              ^{entryWidget}
              <div>
                  <input type=submit value=_{MsgNewEntry}>
$nothing
    <p>
        <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}>_{MsgLoginToPost}
|]

postBlogR :: Handler RepHtml
postBlogR = do
  ((res, entryWidget), enctype) <- runFormPost entryForm
  case res of
    FormSuccess entry -> do
              entryId <- runDB $ insert entry
              setMessageI $ MsgEntryCreated $ entryTitle entry
              redirect $ EntryR entryId
    _ -> defaultLayout $ do
              setTitleI MsgPleaseCorrectEntry
              [whamlet|
<form method=post enctype=#{enctype}>
    ^{entryWidget}
    <div>
        <input type=submit value=_{MsgNewEntry}>
|]

-- comment form
commentForm         :: EntryId -> Form Comment
commentForm entryId = renderDivs $ Comment
                      <$> pure entryId
                      <*> aformM (liftIO getCurrentTime)
                      <*> aformM requireAuthId
                      <*> areq textField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentName) Nothing
                      <*> areq textareaField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentText) Nothing

getEntryR :: EntryId -> Handler RepHtml
getEntryR entryId = do
  (entry, comments) <- runDB $ do
          entry <- get404 entryId
          comments <- selectList [] [Asc CommentPosted]
          return (entry, map entityVal comments)
  muser <- maybeAuth
  (commentWidget, enctype) <- generateFormPost (commentForm entryId)
  defaultLayout $ do
    setTitleI $ MsgEntryTitle $ entryTitle entry
    [whamlet|
<h1>#{entryTitle entry}
<article>#{entryContent entry}
    <section .comments>
        <h1>_{MsgCommentsHeading}
        $if null comments
            <p>_{MsgNoComments}
        $else
             $forall Comment _entry posted _user name text <- comments
                 <div .comment>
                      <span .by>#{name}
                      <span .at>#{show posted}
                      <div .content>#{text}
        <section>
            <h1>_{MsgAddCommentHeading}
            $maybe Entity _ user <- muser
                <form method=post enctype=#{enctype}>
                    ^{commentWidget}
                    <div>
                        <input type=submit value=_{MsgAddCommentButton}>
            $nothing
                <p>
                    <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}>_{MsgLoginToComment}
|]
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: Your `isAuthorized` function is never used. Have you indented your code properly?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about yesod, but aren't you trying to allow anyone to access `BlogR`s and `EntryR`s? So `isAuthorized` should be just `return Authorized` in those cases?

Comment: @dflemstr I was wondering if they should be a part of the blog instance. I will try it and edit the code above here to reflect that.

Comment: I changed the indentation, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @dbaupp EntryR is the problem somehow, right now the unauthorized user will be redirected to login only to see the actual blog posts. I want everyone to be able to see this, but only registered users should see the form to add comments. The actual code can be found here: http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/01/blog-example (I have changed it a little to make it work with a newer yesod version).

Comment: @Altair, ok, my previous comment shows my lack of knowledge of Yesod and should be ignored. However, what happens if you comment out the `isAuthorized (EntryR _) True = ...` declaration? (Just to try to narrow down where the problem is.)

Comment: @dbaupp I tried commenting out that part, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem myself.

This line gave me problems:

```
<*> aformM requireAuthId
```

I also had to remove references to the user id field where it was being used in the application.

I don't know why this problem existed in the first place because the widget should only be shown when a user is logged in.

I would however like to have the user id of the user who posted the comment is there another way to do it without reintroducing the problem I had?

Or do you think this is an error within yesod?

Answer (score 0):

(This would be a comment if I was allowed to)
I'm currently learning Yesod myself so this may not be the best way to do it, but you can avoid requireAuthId in the form and still record the user id in a persist field under the comment Entity if you make your form of a different type. Instead of

```
commentForm :: EntryId -> Form Comment
```

Which is a shorthand for

```
commentForm  :: EntryId -> Html -> MForm Blog Blog (FormResult Comment, Widget)
```

You could rearrange the fields and have

```
commentForm  :: EntryId -> Html -> MForm Blog Blog (FormResult (UserId -> Comment), Widget)
```

and supply the user id in the POST handler. 
You could even strip down the form to just

```
commentForm  :: Html -> MForm Blog Blog (FormResult (Text, Textarea), Widget)
commentForm = renderDivs $ (,)
           <$> areq textField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentName) Nothing
           <*> areq textareaField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentText) Nothing
```

and supply everything else in the POST handler.

Alternatively you could probably put generateFormPost under a case branching so the form isn't generated when you aren't logged in, instead of apparently merely not being shown.

Comment: I have to research how to send the other parts to the database, but this looks like a good method.   The idea of not generating the form will not work because the variables will then be undefined.